# How can I limit INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi is there a way to limit my inner join?

so i can limit the output to only return the last 5 match_ids?

```
SELECT t.id
     , ff.match_id
     , ff.time
  FROM football_teams t
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT match_id
            , hometeam_id
            , time
         FROM football_fixtures 
        ORDER 
           BY time DESC 
        LIMIT 5
     ) ff
    ON ff.hometeam_id = t.id
 WHERE t.id IN ( ".$team_id_string." ) 
 ORDER 
    BY t.id
```

i watch to return an array

something like this

array([football_team.id] = array(match_id[1],match_id[2],match_id[3],match_id[4],match_id[5],))

Matt

Comment: How does your query not work?

Comment: You query seems correct for what you've explained.

Comment: hey it returns nothing but if i take the limit out it returns everything

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action:1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: It means that for the first 5 records from football_fixtures there are no records in football_teams

Comment: @AndrejLudinovskov Not exactly, it means that for the first 5 records there are no records with `id IN ( ".$team_id_string." ) ` Or no record at all at this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the comments, I assume the 5 newest records in `football_fixtures` table doesn't match the other criteria in your query, therefore - doesn't return anything. I'd suggest to put the limit in the outer query to make sure 5 records are being selected :

```
SELECT s.* FROM 
    (SELECT 
            football_teams.id,
            ff.match_id,
            ff.time
            FROM football_teams 
    INNER JOIN football_fixtures ff
     ON hometeam_id=football_teams.id
    WHERE football_teams.id IN ( ".$team_id_string." )
    ORDER BY ff.time
    LIMIT 5) s
ORDER BY s.id
```

Comment: this wont work for what im try to achieve. i can up to 20 team ids, this will limit them to 5, and return 1 match_id for each team id if that makes sense :s

Comment: Then try to explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: The only array which MySql knows is JSON array. So the plan is 1) emulate row_number() http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/ in subquery 2) pivot 5 rows as cols by row number 3) JSON_ARRAY(col1,.. col5)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this form for your query. I removed the join because it doesn't make sense to use in this particular query.

```
SELECT t.match_id, t.hometeam_id as id, t.time FROM (   
    SELECT match_id, hometeam_id, time
    FROM football_fixtures  
    WHERE hometeam_id IN ( ".$team_id_string." ) 
    ORDER BY time DESC 
    LIMIT 5
) as t
ORDER BY id
```